# DESC command in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

What is the use of DESC command in **SQL**?

Comment: What is that command about? Never heard of it....

Comment: @NicoHaase . . . In MySQL, it is short for `describe` and is a valid command.

Comment: @GordonLinoff In MySQL is not a command...

Comment: Command or not, but it really seems to be a shortcut for DESCRIBE which is an alias for EXPLAIN. See [demo](http://rextester.com/JIP93508).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"desc" by itself isn't a command. I suppose you mean "ORDER BY field DESC"
the "desc" means that the results obtained from the query will be showed in descending order.

Example:

Suppose you have a bills table with an id field and a total of 5 rows in that table. Those five rows have id: 1 (row 1), 2 (row 2) and so on. Well with a query of this type:

```
SELECT id FROM bills ORDER BY id DESC
```

You will get as query result:

5
4
3
2
1

Why? because you asked for descending order in the query instruction (from highest number to lowest number) in this case.

Comment: No problem bro!